# MATLAB - Difficulty in getting desired output with Struct

Tags: matlab, struct, output

I have some matlab code I've written but I'm having a problem as is doesn't give the required answer..

When I run

```
track = readTrack('test1.gpx');
disp(track);
```

I get an answer in the form of

```
1x4 struct array containing the fields:

name
points
```

But ideally with the test I should get something like

scalar structure containing the fields:

```
name = Test #1
points =

    0.00000    0.00000    0.00000
    0.00000    2.00000    2.10000
    0.00000    7.00000    4.50000
    0.00000   10.00000   10.00000
```

Any suggestions about how I could change my code to do this and how?

Thanks!! :)

Here is my code.

```
function data = readTrack(filename)
    %creates a struct with fields 'name' and 'points' from data extracted
    %from gpx file. it uses supporting functions. 
    fid=fopen(filename);
    if fid == -1
        result = error (filename); 
    else
        [data,name,point] = setUp(fid);
        while length(point) > 9
            [pointStruct, point] = findLatLongElev(point,fid,name);
            data = [data pointStruct];
        end
    end
end

function result = error(filename)
    % displays error message and produces empty struct
    sprintf('File ''%s'' not found.',filename);
    result = struct();
end

function [data,name,point] = setUp(fid)
    %set up function, finds the name and gets to right place to find the
    %points
    data=[];
    lineSkip(3,fid);
    name = findNameOrElevation(fid);
    lineSkip(13, fid);
    point = fgetl(fid);
end


function lineSkip(n, fid)
    %skips lines
    for i=1:n
        fgetl(fid);
    end
end

function result = findNameOrElevation(fid)
    % finds the name, however also used to find elevation as data presented
    % in similar formats
    line = fgetl(fid);
    findStart = strfind(line,'>');
    findFinish = strfind(line,'<');
    printStart = findStart(1)+1;
    printFinish = findFinish(2)-1;
    result = line(printStart:printFinish);
end

function [pointStruct, point] = findLatLongElev(point,fid,name)
    % finds latitude, longitude and elevation and creates a struct field
    % entry for each set of points
    apostrophes = strfind(point, '"');
    latStart = apostrophes(1)+1;
    latFinish = apostrophes(2)-1;
    longStart = apostrophes(3)+1;
    longFinish = apostrophes(4)-1;
    trackPoint(1) = str2double(point(latStart:latFinish));
    trackPoint(2) = str2double(point(longStart:longFinish));
    trackPoint(3)= str2double(findNameOrElevation (fid));
    fgetl(fid);
    point = fgetl(fid);
    pointStruct = struct(...
        'name',name,...
        'points', trackPoint);
end
```

Comment: Well your code is creating `struct`s so I don't se why you would think the result wouldn't be a `struct`. Try `track.name` and `track.points` instead of `name` and `points`.

Comment: Sorry, but I cannot see the need for a scalar structure. Can you please give the relation to the scalar structure compared to the current output.

Comment: The need is as a requirement for the code it must give that when it is tested!

Comment: @SamuelMetcalfe Ok, but I do still not know how the scalar struct relates to the struct array, This is why my answer is a guess. Can you please try to give the relation between the expected output and the struct array. Further, since my answer apparently is good enough you should try to give a better explanation of your needs. The answer provides 2 ways to solve the issue as it appears from your question. Can you please explain why that does not solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I hope that I can get the relationship between the scalar struct and the stuct array right here. The guess is that one row in the scalar field is supposed to correspond to one element from the same field from the struct array. The question could be edited to make this clearer if I am correct. So to the answer,

In the function `readTrack` you actually explicitly state that you want to have a struct array.

```
while length(point) > 9
    [pointStruct, point] = findLatLongElev(point,fid,name);
    data = [data pointStruct]; % <--Here! Adds another element to an array of structs.
end
```

To have a scalar struct you can catenate each element instead.

```
while length(point) > 9
    [pointStruct, point] = findLatLongElev(point,fid,name);
    data.name = [data.name; mat2cell(pointStruct.name,1,length(pointStruct.name))];
    data.point = [data.point; pointStruct.point];
end
```

However, you need to convert the name to a cell since strings are not necessarily of the same length and should in most cases* not be assumed such. This will also need to be done in `setUp`

```
 data={};
```

I would however, guess that the code will be more readable if you rathered kept the current output catenated the fields afterwards in a separate function. This can be done for each field with `vertcat`. However, you will still get a "matrix dimensions are not consistent" error unless all strings are of the same length or the field data.name is cell. This can be done with a loop since the field names can be obtained from the function `fieldnames`.

* An exception may be if a string is used to represent something else, eg. 8 characters can be used to represent a 64-bit integer.